# Adding spacing between ticks on y-axis GG PLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

```
df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
  boxOdds = 
   c(2.23189,1.315737,1.22866,.8197413,.9802449,.9786673,.6559005,.5929812),
  boxCILow = 
   c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142),
  boxCIHigh = 
  c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584)
)


(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
      .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, color = 'orange') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio (log scale)') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ='Model p < 0.001\nPseudo 
R^2 = 0.10', size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle('Intention to remove box 
turtles from the road')
)
```

I have an odds ratio plot like so[image]

How can I add spacing within the y-axis? I would like the plot to be more spaced out and possibly longer as well.

Comment: Either resize your plot window (R or RStudio) or change the plot dimensions for whatever mechanism you're using to render. If rmarkdown, then `fig.height=...`.

Comment: `fig.height` gives me the intended look when I run the code chunk, but when I render it, doesn't actually change. Do youknow how to resolve this?

Comment: Try modifying `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) )` so that you expand the limits for more space.

Comment: I don't know how you're using `fig.height`, so it's hard to know for certain. If you add a minimal reprex to your question, there's a better chance of finding the culprit. (By reprex, I mean: a representative data sample and a complete-enough rmarkdown document that has at least one code block that creates this plot.)

Comment: (That includes `boxLabels`, which I'm inferring is a `character` vector.)